# Imagen no se alinea al texto

Tags: html, css

En el encabezado de mi página tengo un logo y un título.

También tengo un pie de página con un texto y una imagen.

El problema es que en el encabezado, ambos elementos están descolocados.

Y tanto en el encabezado como en el pie de página, quisiera saber si es posible que el texto esté literalmente en el centro, sin que haga caso a la imagen que haya, ya que sale desplazada. (Y sin tener problemas al redimensionar o cualquier cosa así)

Este es mi código actual, que aún con un `vertical-align: middle;` no funciona.

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  width:200px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 85px;
  background-color:#ff3333;
  color:white;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.header span{
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  }
  
  
/* FOOTER */

#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
 background-color: #171717;
 color:#777766;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
 text-align:center;
 overflow: hidden;
 position:fixed;
 
}

#footer span {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: table-cell;
}

.back-to-top {
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 60;
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #171717;
}

.back-to-top i {
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
 <div class="logo"><img src="images/Logo_Logytel.jpg"></div>
  <span><h2> Formulario</h2></span><br> 
 </div>

<div id="footer">
   <span>© Empresa 2020</span>
   <a class="back-to-top" style="display: inline;" href="#">
    <img src="images/back_to_top.png" alt="Back to Top">
   </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solucion que se me ocurre a lo que propones es posicionar la imagen de forma absoluta, de esta forma, el texto no tomará en cuenta el posicionamiento, y al ser un header no te afectará en nada.

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #ff3333;
  color: white;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.header span {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* FOOTER */

#footer {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #171717;
  color: #777766;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}

#footer span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.back-to-top {
  background: none;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 60;
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #171717;
}

.back-to-top i {
  font-size: 60px;
}


}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/Logo_Logytel.jpg"></div>
    <span><h2> Formulario</h2></span><br>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <span>© Empresa 2020</span>
    <a class="back-to-top" style="display: inline;" href="#">
      <img src="images/back_to_top.png" alt="Back to Top">
    </a>
  </div>

</body>
```